# Firestore Rules Simulator - Request is Null for subcollections

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-tools

The following rules produce an error on "request" in the nested (**) match:

**Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [10], column [30]. Null value error.**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Allow users to only edit their records
    match /users/{userId}{
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;   
      match /{documents=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }    

  }
}
```

The simulator test that is failing is:

`GET: /users/MyUserId/items/MyItemId`

This is using "password" authentication, but even running this as "unauthenticated" produces the same error, as if the rule is not being compiled correctly by the simulator.

Comment: How exactly are you testing this?  Where are you seeing that error message?  Subcollections shouldn't behave any differently than top-level collections.

Comment: In the Simulator. You made a good point and it seems to work correctly live, just not in the simulator, so it must be a bug with the simulator itself.

Comment: The simulator is known to have issues.  It's not an exact simulation of the actual rules engine.  That said, there should be nothing wrong with its handling of subcollections.  If you want to test against the actual engine, use the emulator.  It takes some time to set up, but it's worth it.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

Comment: Altered the question for clarity. The specific error that occurs at "request" is: Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [6], column [28]. Null value error.

Comment: I don't have any problems with your rules that error with the null request.  Maybe you should should the entire set of rules (not just one match) along with the query (you didn't say how you configured authentication, if at all).

Comment: Updated the example to the full one and changed the description to reflect that.

Comment: I am having the same problem, I get a null pointer when simulating without authentication. It seems to be a simulator issue.

Answer (score 1):

Further troubleshooting shows it works live in the database, just not in the simulator. So must be a simulator bug.

Comment: We still haven't established this is in fact a simulator bug, since you haven't said exactly what you're doing with it that doesn't work the way you expect.